# showing image in gridview from byte array

Tags: c#, image, gridview

I have a following problem:
I am using c# and .aspx pages. On .aspx page i have a GridView. I set a GridView datasource to be:

```
GridView1.DataSource = PictureInfo.PictureInfoList;
```

My "PictureInfo" class looks like this:

```
public class PictureInfo
{

    public static List<PictureInfo> PictureInfoList = new List<PictureInfo>();

    public string PictureDescription { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible and how to show a picture which is in "byte[] Picture" in a GridView? Or which way it is possible? I'm saving data in this way before i send it to a database. And i would like to show it in a GridView before i send it to a database. As you can see I'm a beginner but i would be very happy if i could make this work. My head hearts already from reading some solutions online, none helped until now.

thank you very much

Comment: [Hope this link will helpfull to you as well][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182502/how-to-show-image-from-database-in-aspimage-with-linq/17315633#17315633

Answer (score 0):

**on your handler.ashx**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

{

```
 context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
 string ImageID=request["ID"];
 //byte[] ImageByte=pictureInfo.Picture;//local imageByte
 byte[] ImageByte=getImage(ImageId);//image byte from any other sour,e.g database
 Stream strm = new MemoryStream(ImageByte));
 long length = strm.Length;
 byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
 int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);

 while (byteSeq > 0)
 {
       context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
       byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);
  }
```

}

**now** *set image url for your asp:image inside your gridview as follows*

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "somthing.ashx?ID="+userImageID;
```

i hope you have unique id for your image to be visible. I hope you have all set now. Comments and query are well comed.

### retrieve image byte from database

```
public  byte[] GetImage(string ImageId)
{ byte[] img = null;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "SlikaHendler";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ImageId);
cmd.Connection = yourConnection();
SqlDataReader dr = null;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read())
{
    img = (byte[])dr[0];
}
dr.Close();
return img;//returns array of byte
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it is useful, but i think that is not what i was looking for. In my case i have a GridView and a class with info i then put in GridView. I am not sure how to use Handler in this case. I have for ex. 3 entries in my PictureInfoList, so i will have 3 pictures. How to get them from a List<PictureInfo> to be shown in a GridView? Thank you.

Comment: i hope you have byte [] any way. hope you have picture unique id in your list.i might not be right bt you can simply create handler. On it get your byte there it will return image.would you send me your code progress for reference.

Comment: i don't know how to create a handler in my case. u have my code up there in my question. I could add a field in PictureInfo class as picture id, but i don't see how it helps me

Comment: I hope you know how to create handler in asp.net. If you know its ok. If not then goto solution explorer=>>add new item==>generic handler.On it use my code.Use querystring to pass your image id.than from that page get you byte to it.Try it. And update your progress.

Comment: I have edited my answer for your reference again. Hope now it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry for very late reply, i solved issue differently. Now i have a problem with getting a picture from a stored procedure in SQL Server. It just isn't working. I will vote up your answer if i find it useful when i fix my stored procedure. Maybe you could help - stored procedure goes like: 'ALTER procedure [dbo].[SlikaHendler]
(at)ID int
AS
SELECT Picture FROM KP WHERE ID = (at)ID' . Picture is of type image. I will very much try to reply sooner, as i really need a solution now. :)

Comment: @kiriz .. its okie . I am glad that it was helpful to you.. I have added comments on my above answer.. edited for you.. hope you will understand. If my answer is helpful then click right if not then you will discus for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you a solution for: Converting `byte[]` to `Bitmap` (may it will be useful for you):

```
public BitmapSource ByteArrayToBitmap(byte[] byteArray) {
    BitmapSource res;
    try {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray)) {
            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(stream)) {
                res = ToBitmap(bmp);
            }
        }
    } catch {
        res = null;
    }
    return res;
}

public BitmapSource ToBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
        bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);

        stream.Position = 0;
        var result = new BitmapImage();
        result.BeginInit();     
        result.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        result.StreamSource = stream;
        result.EndInit();
        result.Freeze();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Next, you should adapt, and include the `Bitmap` in your `GridView`.

Answer (score -1):

I know pictures are recorded as binaries to databases. In this aspect, your problem turns to a "converting binary to byte".

If you can reach your picture info as binary data, you can convert it as taking 3 digits for 1 byte, and convert & show as bytes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: it is not a issue for me to put byte[] Picture in a database, if i understood you correctly. What i don't know is how to show image from byte[] Picture or any other type, doesn't have to be byte[], in a GridView. Thank you